# In Economics, should I submit first and arxiv second?

Tags: peer-review, arxiv, economics

I'm working outside academia, and have a background in applied maths. In the past few years I've studied economics in some depth, and have nearly finished writing a paper.

I have a good idea to which journal I should submit it, but have doubts on the way to proceed.

> should I submit first and arxiv second, or the other way round?

Since the paper has not been seen by someone else, it might be better to get feedback from arxiv readers first. At the same time, I gather competiton is quite fierce and I'm a bit anxious about being scooped: submitting first and arxiving a couple months later would be some form of protection.

Comment: I don't understand why you're worried about being scooped if you put your paper on arXiv first. By doing submitting to arXiv, you have a public and permanent online record that you did the work first.

Comment: Thanks for this, but wouldn't there be a grey area if someone submitted a rephrased version of my work within a couple days?

Comment: And what do you imagine would happen if someone submitted a rephrased version of your work a few days later? (Rephrased is notably different than done in parallel.) Scooping is really not frequent

Comment: Thanks, I may well be overly cautious, after all what matters is that the ideas are out and tested.

Comment: Consult the (web site for) the journal, to see whether submitting to arXiv first would disqualify the paper from submission to that journal.

Comment: Thank you, the journal in question does allow a preprint first, and yes it does appear to be quite rare in economics.